# Copying Joomla site from server to local

Tags: joomla-3.x

Recently it was asked me to collaborate to the development of a web site created using Joomla. The site is already online in a public server.

I need to copy the entire site to my pc in which Joomla is installed. Is there an easy way to do so?

Comment: Use Akeeba Backup as suggested by @Star. Note that Akeeba Backup will copy both Joomla and your content, so make sure you restore it to an empty folder, not a folder containing Joomla already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes -

Download [Akeeba Backup](https://www.akeebabackup.com/download/akeeba-backup.html). Install this extension and take a backup through admin screen - Components > Akeeba Backup > Backup Now.

Transfer your backup located at `administrator/components/com_akeeba/backup` from local to server or server to local using FTP.

Then download [Kickstart](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-kickstart.html).

Place `kickstart.php` and your backup archive in the same (empty) folder on localhost - such as htdocs (In my case htdocs is my root folder because I use Xamp).

Then run `localhost/kickstart.php` from your browser - The process from here is simple.

Comment: NOTE: Kickstart is just one method of restoring an Akeeba backup. You don't have to use it.

Comment: NOTE: If you do not use kickstart, your backup cannot be used. So you have to use kickstart if you want to extract the backup and restore the site.

Comment: My comment was not meant to detract from your post- regardless your comment is WRONG. A method of restoring an Akeeba backup that does not rely on Kickstart is to extract the backup to your joomla root folder and then to visit localhost/installation (or localhostip/installation) in your browser and install your backup.

Comment: This comment is not wrong - PROVE IT-  So you have to use kickstart if you want to extract the backup and restore the site. - This is the file provided by Akeeba. - I have restored more than 2000 sites like that and thats how I know it.

Comment: "If you are not using Kickstart, you can access the restoration script by typing http://www.example.com/installation/index.php in your browser's address bar, substituting www.example.com with your site's domain name." https://www.akeebabackup.com/documentation/quick-start-guide/using-abi.html and https://www.akeebabackup.com/documentation/quick-start-guide/using-angie.html

Comment: @moomoochoo - I have a question for you -  HOW do you extract a jpa file (default backup from akeeba) on windows 7 without kickstart ? Want to see if I can learn something. Installation folder that you keep mentioning you say is available only after extraction.

Comment: "Akeeba eXtract Wizard is cross-platform. It runs on Windows, Linux and Mac OS X. It will extract all your backup archives: ZIP, JPA and JPS. With blazing fast native code, you don't even need a web server." https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-extract-wizard.html

Comment: There again - I know that - Why didnt you mention that in your comment? The way you said, I thought you could simple extract it - It needs ANOTHER download -  Arent we confusing people with more downloads and more steps? Lets keep it simple - People who are reading this - Kickstart is the right way to restore backup. If you dont have kickstart -  Like the gentleman noted, you need to download extractor . Lets keep it simple for readers.

Comment: And the link "example.com/installation/index.php" that he mentioned above is not available without extracting the jpa backup file into your sites folder - The gentleman just completely missed mentioning that step which is the key to his answer being functional. WHY do all this when kickstart.php DOES IT ALL for you? :)

Comment: @Star try not to get offended by the comments, I'm pretty sure he was just trying to add some clarification that is technically true. (You can use other methods to extract and install the backup, but kickstart is probably the easiest, which is what the question asked for.) I'm not going to delete the comments since there is some useful links and info hidden in there.