# Akeeba Backup wrong paths

Tags: akeebabackup

I used the procedure of this answer ( https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/7613/1685 ) to backup my site on a local.

I did the extraction and the installation in a subdir (`/var/www/html/my_dir/`) of the localhost path (`/var/www/html/`). The entire procedure gave me no errors but if I access to the local site (`localhost/my_dir`) I see the homepage exactly as it should be but other pages are wrongly linked. If a click to a link to page2 the browser go to `localhost/index.php/page` instead of going to `localhost/my_dir/index.php/page` and clearly a get a "Not found" error message. If I go manually (typing the right address) to page2, the page looks correct.

I think there is some option that has to be setted to let joomla recognise that I have a subdir but I don't know how to set it.

Comment: In your configuration.php file, try using `localhost/my_dir` for the `$live_site` variable. I personally always use a Virtual Host so problems like this never occur. If you want to know how to set one up, please have a look at the following [tutorials](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/4157/168)

Comment: @Lodder already tried, ot doesn't work. Not only the links remain wrong but also the homepage is no more rendered correctly (missing images and probably some .css files)

Comment: And have you made any manual changes to your htaccess file?

Comment: @Lodder no, no changes

Comment: well personally I would go down the Virtual Host route. I believe this will also solve your issue, but before, can you try rebuilding your menu items as shown in [this screenshot](https://docs.joomla.org/Help33:Menus_Menu_Item_Manager)

Comment: @Lodder You think virtual host will work because in that way I can set the `DocumentRoot` property in the `.conf` file?

Comment: I'm about 90% sure this will fix the issue. But as mentioned, try rebuilding your menu items first

Comment: @Lodder thank you, I will first try with the virtual host, rebuilding the menu items every time would be annoying.

Comment: Rebuilding is done with the click of 1 button. I don't actually mean re-creating them. See here https://docs.joomla.org/Help33:Menus_Menu_Item_Manager

Comment: @Lodder with a virtual host it works and I think it is the best solution. Maybe it's better to create an answer for this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too sure of the technical terms and why this will work, but I would suggest creating a Virtual Host. Using this will allow you to use a domain (so to speak), such as `joomla.loc` which you can map to the existing Joomla installation directory.

Using sub-directories for websites can start causing lots of issues, especially with CMS's such as Jomla or Wordress, therefore when creating a new installation on the same server, it's best to use subdomains (live host) or virtual host (localhost).

The following tutorials that have been compiled for different environments can be found here:

https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/4157/168

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an error with your .htaccess file. check the following line:

```
RewriteBase /
```

As you're running on localhost within a sub-Directory (your main "domain" is http://localhost), you should set it to `RewriteBase /my_dir` (replace my_dir with the actual Directory of your Joomla installation.)